# getting id of new data which is added every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
console.log(
  "this.props.lessonPlans.lessons inside index.js  is",
  this.props.lessonPlans.lessons.data.length,
);
let datacheck;
datacheck = this.props.lessonPlans.lessons.data;
console.log("datacheck is", datacheck);
datacheck.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
  var x = arrayItem._id;
  console.log(x);
});
```

I have say 14 data in my lessonPlans.data and when I console log, I get all the _ids of 14 data, however when I add a new data to lessons every time the length of the data array would increase by one but I need to get the id of that new data being added. How do I get the id of the newly added data every time?

Comment: Could you please provide a working example or complete code snippet? It's hard to work on something like this.

Comment: Can you show the part where you are adding the new data and the part where you want to access the new data